# jQuery - loop through ol with li containing tables, and get data from table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list (ul) whose list item (li) elements each contain a table with 2 columns (first column is a delete button (attribute 'data-id' contains the id of the data), second column is the data text). I need to get the values inside the table of each li and add the values to a hidden field for processing on the server. How would I go about retrieving the values from the table inside the li. I know how to loop through the ul itself and pull out each li...

```
$('#ol li').each(function (i, li) {
    var listItem = li;
    // Get data from table within li here
});
```

but I am not sure how to proceed after this step. Thank you for any help.

EDIT

Here is an example of what gets appended to the ol.

```
$('#ol').append("<li><table><tbody><tr><td style='padding-right:16px'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger remove' data-id='" + item.val() + "'><b>X</b></button></td><td>" + txt + "</td></tr></tbody></table></li>");
```

SOLUTION

Using find() I was able to locate the desired elements and extract the values.

```
$('#ol li').each(function () {

        var id = $(this).find('td').first().find('button').attr('data-id');

        if(id == -1)
        {
            var txt = $(this).find('td').last().text();

            $('#hf').val($('#hf').val() + txt + "|");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#hf').val($('#hf').val() + id + "|");
        }

    });
```

Thank you to those who assisted.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: please post your html for being more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the two columns of the data like so:

```
$('#ol li').each(function (i, li) {
    var listItem = li;
    var column1 = $(li).find("td").first().text();
    var column2 = $(li).find("td").last().text();
    // do things with columns
});
```

I'm assuming you just have a 2x1 table with a simple text value in each.

Comment: The first column contains a delete button (which also contains the ID of the data text), the second column contains the data text.

Answer (score 2):

You should read up on the usage of the `this` keyword.

So, when you run a function like this -

```
$('#ol li').each(function(){
    $(this).val()  //returns the value of the current li that is being looped through
});
```

The way the `.each()` function works is the same way as a loop, so it goes through every `#ol li` element one at a time, and you utilize `this` to access the current element that is being looped through.

So now, from here, you can search for the required children. You will most likely also have to utilize jquery's `.data()` function to get the information stored in the `data-id` attribute.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: That is much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: @PatCoombe Not a problem. So now, you can use `$(this)` and think of it as the `li` containing the table. From there I believe you can grab the information from the children